# How to move from one window to another using buttons in Dr racket?

Tags: racket

I would like to know how to implement a window that contains a button and when clicking on this button another window appears, I do not know how to implement that

Comment: What have you tried? You have to have tried at least something...

Answer (score 3):

First, I highly recommend you read the [Racket GUI Docs](https://docs.racket-lang.org/gui/), especially [the first part](https://docs.racket-lang.org/gui/windowing-overview.html) as it contains some good information on getting started.<sup>1</sup>

As with many GUI toolkits, you build frames with panes as children, that have their own sub panes all the way down until you eventually reach primitive widgets like buttons and text fields. The `racket/gui` collection uses Racket's class system. First, make sure the first line of your program reads `#lang racket/gui`. Next, creating (and showing) a pane is just:

```
(define fr (new frame% [label "Frame Generator"]))
(send fr show #t)
```

Here, [`frame%`](https://docs.racket-lang.org/gui/frame_.html?q=frame%25) is a class, the `%` is not special in Racket, and is just a convention for saying "This identifier is a class." We also gave this new frame a label `"Frame Generator"`, and bound it to `fr`. Finally, we showed the frame. If this program used C style syntax it would look something like:

```
var fr = new Frame(lebel="Frame Generator");
fr.show(true);
```

At this point if you run the program your frame will technically appear, but it will be so small you will have a hard time finding it. So lets add a button to your frame:

```
(new button% [parent fr]
     [label "Click Me!"])
```

We didn't bother to bind the button because nothing refers to it besides `fr`, which is set when the button was created.

Now if you run the program you should see something like:

[image: GUI Example]

When you click on the button nothing happens. The [`button%`](https://docs.racket-lang.org/gui/button_.html?q=button%25) class takes a `callback` argument when it is created. It will call the function whenever the button gets clicked. The callback itself must accept two parameters, but for many simple callbacks we can just ignore them. This makes are new button class:

```
(new button% [parent fr]
     [label "Click Me!"]
     [callback (lambda (this event)
                 ...)])
```

Now, you said you wanted to make a new frame whenever you click the button. Based on what I have given you here, can you figure out what to put in the `...` to create (and show) a new frame?

<sub>1There are other gui and rendering systems in Racket such as `big-bang`. I am assuming though that you are trying to get up and running with the default `racket/gui` collection.</sub>